# Confused about which smart contract command to use to transfer my tokens to my other wallet address

Tags: solidity, tokens, smart-contract-wallets, wallet-transfer, airdrop

I'm not a dev, just a web3 enthusiast with a very basic knowledge of solidity. Recently, I found out that I'm eligible for the airdrop. However, my main wallet was compromised and I would like to claim my to tokens to my other safe wallet address through the smart contract.

I found out that I need to input unit256 integer as my number of tokens (my exact number of tokens + 18 zeros (wei) to interact with the smart contract. Command [ claimableTokens method Response ] uint256

However, I am not sure which command to use to redirect my tokens to my safe wallet successfully.

There is a command setRecipients but as far as I understand it contains the string of addresses _recipients (address[]). Can I input just one address into the line _recipients (address[])? Will it allow me to redirect my tokens successfully, or should I use the line _sweepReceiver (address)? And please, tell me what does  _sweepReceiver (address) stand for?[[image]]Screenshot[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2iNN.png)

Comment: No whitelisting, the compromised address is eligible. My question is can I use this command to redirect tokens to my safe address?

Comment: If your compromised address is eligible then how can it be possible to claim it from another address:)